# Where is zend-framework library?

Tags: software-installation, zend

I've installed zend-framework following the commands:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:zend-framework/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install zend-framework
```

zf.sh works but I was expecting the framework to be in `/usr/local/Zend` and there is nothing...

Where is it supposed to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Zend Framework library code is distributed in the `libzend-framework-php` package which is normally installed automatically as a dependency of the `zend-framework` package. The library code is installed in `/usr/share/php/libzend-framework-php/Zend/` directory.

You can view listing of any installed package with command:

```
dpkg -L PACKAGE_NAME
```

(or use synaptic for GUI)

Comment: Thanks a lot.That was indeed it's location. And thanks for the tip about dpkg -L